# Sort array order of lower and uppercase

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Suppose we have a following array

```
let names = ['Malek', 'malek', 'sana', 'ghassen', 'Ghada', 'Samir']; 
console.log(names.sort());
```

the result is a follows:

```
["Ghada", "Malek", "Samir", "ghassen", "malek", "sana"]
```

JavaScript compares each character according to its ASCII value.

I want to sort by lowercase letters to come first in the sorted array,

the expected output:

```
 ["Ghada", "ghassen", "malek", "Malek", "Samir", "sana"]
```

thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try this with **localeCompare**:

```js
const names = ["Ghada", "Malek", "Samir", "ghassen", "malek", "sana"];
const result = names.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b)); 

console.log(result);
```

The localeCompare() method returns a number indicating whether the string comes before, after or is equal as the compareString in sort order.

Answer (score 1):

Try out as,

```js
let names = ['Malek', 'malek', 'sana', 'ghassen', 'Ghada', 'Samir']; 
console.log(names.sort(function(a, b) {
  var nameA = a.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  var nameB = b.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
  if (nameA < nameB) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (nameA > nameB) {
    return 1;
  }

  // names must be equal
  return 0;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Intl.Collator()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator):

```js
let names = ['Malek', 'malek', 'sana', 'ghassen', 'Ghada', 'Samir', "A", 'a', 'ba', 'Ba', 'Cd', 'ca']; 
let res = names.sort(Intl.Collator('en').compare);

console.log(res);
```